# Why default datetime is not changing in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code. Here, `get_time()` is returning the same value even after 5 secs, why is that so?

```
from datetime import datetime

import time


def get_time(time_now=datetime.now()):
    print('Current time', time_now)


get_time()
time.sleep(5)
get_time()
```

Answer (score 2):

Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called. So if you want `time_now` to be evaluated in each function call then you have to do something like this,

```
def get_time():
    print('Current time', datetime.now())
```